# Python - Sumar 2 columnas y el resultado agregarlo a una columna existente

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo varios archivos y he logrado concatenarlos en uno solo, además de borrar algunas columnas y cambiar el nombre de algunas otras, el problema es que uno de los archivos tiene 2 columnas que quiero sumar y que el resultado pase a una columna ya existente (Total GB Datos)

[image: Sumar las dos columnas de la derecha y el resultado quede en Total GB Datos]

En la imagen tengo las dos columnas de la derecha PLMN y la suma de ambos valores quiero que quede en Total GB Datos

```
import pandas as pd # Importacion estandar de la libreria Pandas
import numpy  as np # Importacion estandar de la libreria NumPy
from numpy.random import randn 
import glob

# Directorio de archivos NOTA IMPORTANTE, poner / al final del nombre de la carpeta en directorio
directorio = 'C:/Users/#####/PycharmProjects/Cap-cap/Files/'

# Patrón de archivo para filtrar los archivos de Excel en el directorio
patron_archivos = '*.csv'

# Obtener la lista de archivos de Excel en el directorio
archivos = glob.glob(f"{directorio}/{patron_archivos}")

# Columnas a eliminar
columnas_a_eliminar = ['REGION', 'CITY', 'RNC', 'ENB_AGG', 'MUNICIPALITY',
                       'NSA_TRAFFIC_PDCP_GB_5GENDC_4G5G', 'PROVINCE']

# Diccionario de mapeo para cambiar los nombres de columna
mapeo_nombres = {
'SUM(PMPDCPVOLDLDRB)': 'Datos DL',
'SUM(PMPDCPVOLULDRB)': 'Datos UL',
'SUM(L_THRP_BITS_DL)': 'Datos DL',
'SUM(L_THRP_BITS_UL)': 'Datos UL',
}

# Crear una lista para almacenar los datos de cada archivo
datos = []

for archivo in archivos:
df = pd.read_csv(archivo)

# Cambiar los nombres de columna según el diccionario de mapeo
df.rename(columns=mapeo_nombres, inplace=True)

# Verificar la existencia de cada columna antes de eliminarla
existentes = df.columns.tolist()
columnas_eliminar = [col for col in columnas_a_eliminar if col in existentes]
if columnas_eliminar:
    df = df.drop(columnas_eliminar, axis=1)  # Elimina las columnas especificadas

datos.append(df)

# Unir los datos de todos los archivos en un único DataFrame
datos_combinados = pd.concat(datos)

# Guardar el resultado en un nuevo archivo Excel
datos_combinados.to_excel('datos_combinados.xlsx', index=False)
```

lo intente con

```
df["Total GB Datos"] = df["PLMN_1_TRAFFIC_GB"] + df["PLMN_2_TRAFFIC_GB"]
```

también intente crear las variables

```
# Columnas a sumar
columnas_a_sumar = ["PLMN_1_TRAFFIC_GB","PLMN_2_TRAFFIC_GB"]

# Nueva columna para el resultado de la suma
nueva_columna = "Total Gb Datos"
```

y luego dentro del for

```
df[nueva_columna] = df[columnas a sumar].sum(axis=1)
```

pero en ninguno de los dos logre que me colocara la suma de las columnas PLMN en Total Gb Datos

De antemano agradezco su apoyo.

Comment: Buen día, no sé si fue error al redactar tu pregutna pero el `for` está mal indentado. ¿Podrías crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) donde se pueda reproducir tu problema? También agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` con las que se pueda reproducir el problema. Oprime [edit] para agregar la información faltante.

Comment: Hola, me parece que la siguiente parte puede estar dando problemas:

`mapeo_nombres = {
'SUM(PMPDCPVOLDLDRB)': 'Datos DL',
'SUM(PMPDCPVOLULDRB)': 'Datos UL',
'SUM(L_THRP_BITS_DL)': 'Datos DL',
'SUM(L_THRP_BITS_UL)': 'Datos UL',
}`
Pues crea columnas duplicadas en el `pd.DataFrame` y si estas columnas son las que son sumadas, el resultado sera una seria de NA. Por que no pruebas cambiando el nombre de estas columnas para que no esten duplicadas (Datos_DL y Datos_DL2) o (sumandos estas columnas en una sola).  

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta verificar que los valores sean numéricos. Una forma sería hacer algo así (y de esta manera rellenas los espacios vacíos por nans):

`df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)`